# writing data frames to a sql table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pypyodbc

I'm reading from one database and outputting certain columns to another database.
I use a data frame to store the data and then iterate through the frame to output the column i'm interested in.:

```
for i in range(0,len(myframe.index)):
    cursor_conn2.execute(SQL2_UPD_NEWEMP,myframe.loc[i,"LNAME_EMP"])
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
raise TypeError("Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row")
```

This is SQL2_UPD_NEWEMP:

```
SQL2_UPD_NEWEMP="INSERT INTO DBO.NEW_EMP_CAL(LNAME) VALUES(?)"
```

there is data in the frame. 113 rows, and LNAME_EMP is a valid name, and every row contains data.

This should be quite simple, but I'm not seeing where the error is being made, and it makes me sad.

When I run this code I see all the data:

```
for i in range(0,len(myframe.index)):
    print(myframe.loc[i,"LNAME_EMP"])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are passing a scalar as parameter. But as error clearly mentions, your parameter must be an iterable such as tuple:

```
cursor_conn2.execute(SQL2_UPD_NEWEMP, (myframe.loc[i,"LNAME_EMP"],))
```

Or a list:

```
cursor_conn2.execute(SQL2_UPD_NEWEMP, [myframe.loc[i,"LNAME_EMP"]])
```

Comment: That is a pandas error. And you need to pass separate values into parameters equal to the number of param placeholders, `?`. `cur.execute(sql, [myframe.loc[i,"LNAME_EMP"], myframe.loc[i,"MNAME"]])`.

Comment: Somehow I deleted the comment that led to Parfait's response. Essentially I asked how it was possible to add columns to the sql insert statement. Parfaits response, was spot on.